# Double click on TreeView causes MenuItem click on new window

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, menuitem, double-click

I have a TreeView that opens a new window when the user double clicks on a TreeViewItem. This new window is placed in front and at the center (`WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"`) of the previous window (the window with the TreeView). Sometimes when this new window opens up, the mouse is directly on top of a MenuItem of the new window, and it causes the MenuItem Click event to be fired, which is undesirable in my program. I tried setting e.Handled to true in the TreeView MouseDoubleClick handler, and it didn't change this behavior.

Here is my TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" MouseDoubleClick="treeView_MouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MessageHeaders}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource childrenDataTemplate}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModuleName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And treeView_MouseDoubleClick:

```
private void treeView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        APIEditorWindow editor = new APIEditorWindow();
        editor.Owner = this;
        editor.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the menu item that has the Click event only requires a single click, you could check if it was triggered from a double click

```
private void MenuItemClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        // your code
    }
    // if it was activated from a double click, code will be ignored
}
```

Other suggestions might be trying `Preview` events and using `e.Handled = true` if the above solution is not satisfactory

Comment: MenuItem Click event has `RoutedEventArgs` as input, not `MouseButtonEventArgs`, which doesn't contain the click count.  I tried using the `Preview` events and that didn't work.